# Relationship between Sharpe Ratio and Investment Horizon in a theoretical IID return world

Tags: risk, sharpe-ratio

In his paper, "The Statistics of Sharpe Ratio", Andrew Lo writes

> "hence, the ratio will increase as the square root of q, making a
> longer horizon investment seem more attractive. This interpretation is
> highly misleading and should not be taken at face value. Indeed, the
> Sharpe ratio is not a complete summary of the risks of a multiperiod
> investment strategy and should never be used as the sole criterion for
> making an investment decision."

While I understand that Sharpe Ratio is not a perfect indicator and the fallacy of risk decrease in long investment horizon, I'm a bit confused on why Lo makes this claim under the IID case. In the theoretical context of IID return and no compounding, isn't it true that long investment is indeed more attractive, given the expectation grows linearly with respect to time, standard deviation is proportional to square root of time, risk adjusted expectation and Sharpe Ratio are proportional to square root of time? In other words, if we are in a absurd world where daily return is IID with a positive expectation, and we invest a fixed amount of money in the beginning of the day and take home whatever left in the end of the day, isn't it always more attractive to repeat this process for more days than less days?

Comment: If you understand "the fallacy of risk decrease in long investment horizon" then you understand why the fall in the Sharpe Ratio with investment horizon under i.i.d is mathematically true but misleading if used to justify long horizon investment as low risk. This is what Lo is saying, the SR can be used/sometimes is used to justify the fallacy that in the long run you practically have no risk at all.

Comment: Hi @nbbo2. If under iid, isn’t the fall in the SR with investment horizon both mathematically true and not misleading? It doesn’t imply that risk is low when investment horizon is long; instead, it’s showing the risk adjusted expectation is higher when investment horizon. Therefore, I believe in this theoretical case, an investor who wants high risk adjusted expectation should choose long time horizon. And I failed to see any misleading parts… Would you mind elaborating more on why it’s misleading?

Comment: In Markowitz Portfolio Theory the investment horizon is fixed (though not clearly specified), and the SR is used to compare two investments for (implicitly) the same investment horizon. In my opinion it is not proper to use SR to compare the same investment in 2 different time horizons. But this is my opinion and I hope other answers/comments will clarify this issue.